# Robot Framework: prepare/clenup database

Tags: mysql, robotframework

I was using `robotframework-databaselibrary` to prepare DB and clean it up after the test execution.

The problem is, that it's require to compile native mysql drivers for every OS that I want to run on:

```
pip install MySQL-python
pip install mysql-connector-python
```

Is there a better mysql **module for Robot Framework** that does not need to be compiled with extra-libraries?

Comment: This is going to the case for any testing framework you decide to use.

Comment: @ILostMySpoon, the question actually about RF modules, I'm not going to change framework itself

Comment: I understand that. You will need drivers regardless. Even if you write your own.